# OracleCommand parameters not being converted in C#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, oracle

I'm trying to setup an OracleConnection in .net which has been successfully working until I tried to add parameters via the OracleCommand. I get the error 'ORA-00903: invalid table name' which is definitely because the parameter isn't converted correctly. If I run the same SQL with the table name hardcoded it executes successfully

```
var cmd = new OracleCommand(@"
SELECT *
FROM :Table
WHERE CLIENT_ID = 'ZARA'
  AND SKU_ID = 'SKU1'
FETCH FIRST :Rows ROWS ONLY
", _connection);
cmd.Parameters.Add("Table", "SKU");
var dr = cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync().Result;
```

I expect this to work return the datareader successfully but it fails with an ORA-00903

Comment: This would fail in all languages and databases. Parameters are used to pass values, not for string interpolation. Query parameters are the same thing as function parameters, a way to pass values to the function or query.

Comment: Side note: `cmd` and `dr` need `using`

Comment: something not right, one is SKU, and the other is SKU1. are you sure the syntax is correct?

Comment: _You can't parameterize table names._ If this really needs to be dynamic (it seems like this would only work for a `SKU` table), then the normal way of handling object identifier parameters is to first do a query to the platform's information schema equivalent to validate the string is correct, and then use normal string concatenation to substitute in the value as returned from the query (rather than the original string value that may have been supplied by the user and use unicode tricks or similar to cause issues), possibly in conjunction with something like `quotename()`

Comment: Thank you everyone! @PanagiotisKanavos is there a preferred method for assigning the table name etc in this scenario?

Comment: Also, this looks suspiciously like you have a common connection object you're re-using throughout the the app. _That's not good._ Because of the connection pooling feature in ADO.Net, this makes things worse, rather than better, and you really should open a brand new connection for each query. So instead of a whole connection object, you should have an easy connection string property you can access.

Comment: @user37213 what are you trying to do in the first place? I suspect the real problem has a better answer. It makes little sense to parameterize the table name when you try to search for such specific fields and values. Are you trying to use manual table partitions instead of using Oracle's built-in partitions? Or trying to create a multi-tenant application by targeting different tables because Oracle makes using different schemas painful?

Comment: My project has a generic Repository which I'm trying to set up dynamic SQL calls to. So depending on which table/repo calls it, it'll need to set the table name & where clause dynamically

Comment: Why don't you use an ORM like Entity Framework or NHibernate instead? Why reinvent low-level CRUD classes (yes, I know you said repository but what does it really do?) when you have a high level ORM and Unit-of-Work, that's already generic and feature-complete?

Comment: In any case it seems that the actual problem is finding a SQL query builder for Oracle, not passing the table as a parameter. You can't pass the table, you'll have to construct the query string and *then* pass any actual values as parameters. Dapper has a [SqlBuilder helper class](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper/tree/main/Dapper.SqlBuilder) and [InterpolatedSql](https://github.com/Drizin/InterpolatedSql/tree/main/src/InterpolatedSql.Dapper) offers an alternative based on FormattableString instead of interpolation